# deleteing keys from nested json objects?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to delete keys from a json object.

```
{ 
"name":"Huntelaar",
"fistname": "Klaas-Jan",
"number": 23,
"clubs": [
    {
        "team":"team",
        "years": 5
    },
    {
        "team":"team",
        "years": 5
    }
]}


$.getJSON("example.json", function (data){
            delete data.firstname;
        )};
```

So this will delete the "firstname" inside the object.
But how can I delete - lets say - every "team" name inside the clubs array? I tried various $.each functions but had no success so far. Thank you very  much.

Comment: "I tried various $.each functions" I don't see any in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
delete data.clubs[0].team
```

where [0] is index, you can choose any possible index in your collection for example right now there are two clubs so you can use

```
delete data.clubs[0].team
delete data.clubs[1].team
```

To delete all team attributes in clubs:

```
for(i=0; i<data.clubs.length; i++)
    delete data.clubs[i].team;
```

Comment: $.each(data.clubs, function(i, v){
delete v.team;
});